# Comprobar si un carácter de un String es un número

Tags: java, string

Quisiera recorrer un `String` y comprobar si cada carácter es un número. La idea es hacerlo mediante el método `.length()` y un bucle `for` para recorrerlo. El problema es que no se como comprobar que cada carácter es un número.
Sería algo como esto:

```
String numCuenta = "2345901526372637";

for(int i = 0; i < numCuenta.length(); i ++){
   if(numCuenta.charAt(i)= .****AQUI ES DONDE NO SE QUE HACER***){

   }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a **StackOverflow** , te recomiendo que realices el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y asi obtengas tu primera medalla, ademas mira [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para asi poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: @Wismo edite tu pregunta ya que tenía algunos detalles, saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para tu pregunta de cómo se resolvería la inversa, es muy sencillo. Simplemente, debes negar la condición que utilizas en el `if`:

```
public void testCadena()
    {
        String numCuenta = "TEST";

        for( int i = 0; i < numCuenta.length(); i++ )
            if( !Character.isDigit( numCuenta.charAt( i ) ) )
                System.out.println( "No numero" );
            else
                System.out.println( "Numero" );
    }
```

La salida es la siguiente:

```
No numero
No numero
No numero
No numero
```

Espero haber resuelto tu duda.

Comment: Genial, mil gracias !!!!!

Comment: @Wismo este método podría fallar si tu cadena tiene "." u otros caracteres, lo mejor es validar mediante un "parseo".

Comment: @Jorgesys No necesariamente se necesita hacer algún "parseo". Simplemente se puede utilizar código ASCII. Por ejemplo: `numCuenta.chatAt(i) >= '0' && numCuenta.charAt <= '9'` De este modo se detecta si el caracter es un dígito. Para hacer el proceso contrario, pues se niega la condición con el operador `!`.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes usar el método:

```
Character.isDigit(<caracter>)
```

de esta forma:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < numCuenta.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(String.valueOf(numCuenta.charAt(i)))){
              System.out.println("Es numerico: "  + numCuenta.charAt(i));
        }else{
            System.out.println("NO es numerico: "  + numCuenta.charAt(i));
        }      
    }
```

pero el problema en este caso es que caracteres como "." mostrará que es un dígito.

**La mejor opción es hacer uso de un método el cual determine si es numérico o no el valor, en caso de ser numérico retornaría un valor `true` en otro caso un `false`**:

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String str) {
    try {
        double d = Double.parseDouble(str);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        return false; //Error no es numerico
    }
    return true; //Es numerico
}
```

El anterior método ayudaría a determinar en tu bucle si cada carácter leído es o no 
numérico, de esta forma:

```
   String numCuenta = "2345901526372637";

    for (int i = 0; i < numCuenta.length(); i++) {
        if (isNumeric(String.valueOf(numCuenta.charAt(i)))){
              System.out.println("Es numerico: "  + numCuenta.charAt(i));
        }else{
            System.out.println("NO es numerico: "  + numCuenta.charAt(i));
        }      
    }
```

usando el método  y teniendo como ejemplo la cadena:

```
String numCuenta = "Wismo 12";
```

obtendrías como salida:

```
NO es numérico: W
NO es numérico: i
NO es numérico: s
NO es numérico: m
NO es numérico: o
NO es numérico:  
Es numérico: 1
Es numérico: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

La comprobación de si es un numero puedes hacerla con el método estático de la clase Character : isDigit() , ten en cuenta que serán validos todos los dígitos especificados en la [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char))

```
for (int i = 0; i < numCuenta.length; i++)
      if(Character.isDigit(numCuenta.charAt(i)))
            System.out.println("Numero");
      else
            System.out.println("No numero");
```

Comment: Gracias, me has solucionado el problema. Me podrías decir si hay un metodo opuesto a este que fuera algo como isNotDigit, es decir que hiciera lo opuesto que comprobara si el parámetro no es un digito

Comment: Si, el mismo metodo xD, cuando te devulva "true" es que es un digito, si te devulve "false" , quiere deccir que no es un digito. Todas las funciones del tipo "is..." que devuleven un tipo de dato boolean sirven tanto para comprobar que lo es , como que no , segun devuleva "true o false"